# Getting "Import Error" while running Python Flask Application

Tags: flask

The following error is getting while attempting to run a sample Python Flask application.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bineeth/Projects/python/xcontent/bin/flask", line 7, in <module>
    from flask.cli import main
  File "/home/bineeth/Projects/python/xcontent/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/home/bineeth/Projects/python/xcontent/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/home/bineeth/Projects/python/xcontent/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 66, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES
  File "/home/bineeth/Projects/python/xcontent/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 31, in <module>
    from werkzeug.datastructures import (# noqa
  File "/home/bineeth/Projects/python/xcontent/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 24, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import dump_options_header, dump_header, generate_etag, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'dump_options_header'
```

Following is the source code;

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ping')
def ping():
    return {'status':'completed'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

I am using Python 3 and LiClipse IDE. Also Linux Mint is the Operating System.
Appreciate your valuable help in this regard.

Comment: Please note that I am a newbie in Python development. Just started learning Flask.

Comment: did you try uninstalling flask, werkzeug and install them again ? this seems to be version compatibility mismatch.